# Why is this c code not working? I cannot access the roll nos using pointers to the structure

Tags: c, struct

Error:  request for member roll in something not a structure or union
I want to use pointers to access the respective roll nos from structure and put them in increasing order using structure pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct student
{
    int roll;
    struct name
    {
        char first[10];
        char last[10];
    };
};
void main()
{
    int i,j;
    struct student stu[10],temp;
    struct student *ptr;
    ptr=stu;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&(*(ptr+i).roll));
    }
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5-i;j++)
            if(*(ptr).roll>*(ptr+i).roll)
            {
                temp = *ptr;
                *(ptr)=*(ptr+i);
                *(ptr+i)=temp;
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: I went ahead and used the code formatting button to format your code. You should do this yourself, next time :)

Comment: also, compiler errors usually contain exactly the line number where things go wrong, and a reference to the "broken" statement. **Alwas paste the verbatim error message, including context**.

Comment: `&(*(ptr+i).roll)` --> `&ptr[i].roll`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member-selection operator (i.e. the dot `.`) have higher [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the dereference operator.

That means the expression `*(ptr + i).roll` is parsed as `*((ptr + i).roll)` which is not correct. You need to use parentheses like `(*(ptr + i)).roll`. *Or* use the arrow operator like in `(ptr + i)->roll`.

Comment: ... or actually use the fact that your `ptr` is really explicitly just a pointer to the first element of your array (because you set it so!) and don't use `(*(ptr+i))` at all, but simply use `stu[i]`.